# 'load' doesn't work in another 'load' callback, but 'ready' does

Tags: jquery

I want to add a callback to 'load' event and want it to be executed at the end of all 'load' callbacks. So I registered a 'load' callback in another 'load' callback but it didn't work. I tried the same logic with 'ready' and it worked.
My question is why this doesn't work with 'load'?

My jQuery version is 3.4.0

```js
//this 'ready' part works
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('ready1');
    $(document).ready(function() {
        console.log('ready2');
    });
});

//this 'load' part doesn't work. Only 'load1' is printed.
$(window).on('load', function() {
    console.log('load1');
    $(window).on('load', function() {
        console.log('load2');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(document).ready` is invoking a special jQuery function, which will run the associated handler once the document is ready, *or*, if the document is already ready, the handler will run immediately. It's a bit like:

```
// $(document).ready:

(callback) => {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    callback();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', callback);
  }
};
```

On the other hand, the `on` handler will *only* attach the listener, without checking to see if the event has already fired:

```
// $(window).on('load'

(callback) => {
  document.addEventListener('load', callback);
};
```

Attaching a listener via `on` is like calling `addEventListener`, and nothing else (so if the `load` event has already fired when `on('load'` is called, the callback will never run). `$(document).ready` has some extra logic involved.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. It's really helpful.